# Tint Color set on Interface Builder generates warning

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5, xcode4.3

I have a segmented control with 2 segments in XIB file. When I set the Tint property to Black it gives me a warning message : ***"Attribute Unavailable : Tint colors set in Interface builder on iOS version prior to 3.0"***. 

I had set the tint color because I need a black segmented control. How Can I remove this warning. I Only want to run my project on iOS version prior to 5.0. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set warning for Interface Builder by searching for "Interface Builder" form **Build Settings** under your **Targets**:

[image]

In Interface Builder, set **Document Versioning** Deployment:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick replay. I dont want to hide the warning I need to resolve it.

Comment: Have you set your **Deployment Target** to later than 3.0?

Comment: What about in the XIB, Document Versioning for Interface Builder? *(see my second screenshot in my answer)*